# File watcher: "An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory"

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, node-sass, file-watcher

> cmd.exe /D /C call C:\Users\sebas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-sass.cmd style.scss:style.css
>   **An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory**

[image]

The scss file I want the file watcher to watch is placed at the root of my project.

Watch the error appear: [gif_link](https://gyazo.com/b1f6a96b410e0b01d9b755d9aa12a61b)

**How do I fix this error?**

Comment: Your `Arguments` field content in File Watcher **is wrong**. It's for Ruby-sass, not node-sass. Run `node-sass --help` to check expected parameters. For example `--output . $FileName$` will output compiled version in the same folder as source file. https://postimg.cc/LqksNkqL

Comment: @LazyOne That is not true. As Lena's explain in her answer, all I had to do was to check the "Create output file from stdout". The arguments are valid commands for node-sass npm. 
Please consider removing your comment to avoid confusing others (I unfortunately can't take back my upvote for some reason).

Comment: Check again. 1) Node-sass does not have `$FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` syntax. To specify output file you need to use `-o` / `--output` option; 2) "Create output file from stdout` does not always work (on some systems/setups; no ideas why). That's why `-o` / `--output` parameter comes instead as it always works.

Comment: If just ticking "Create output file from stdout" option works for you then it's great, no probs.

Comment: I am pretty sure `$FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` is the syntax of the jetbrains "file watcher" plugin in then, all I can say is that it isn't incorrect syntax, and *therefore*, your statement: *"Your Arguments field content in File Watcher is wrong. It's for Ruby-sass, not node-sass."* Is wrong. As your comment is wrong and misleading for users to come, I believe that it would be ideal to delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you like the `.css` files to be generated in the same folder as original file, try the following settings:

[image]

Note the **Create output file from stdout** option - it has to be enabled, as *node-sass* writes CSS to stdout unless the `-o` option is passed.

If you like to place generated files in a separate folder, use the `-o` option:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got same error working with webpack bundler and setting my scripts in package.json

In my case to resolve this issue you need to add output directory ( `-o name-of-directory`).

If working with scripts in `package.json` it should look like this:

```
scripts: {
    "scss": "node-sass --watch src -o src"
}
```

`src` is folder where `sass` file which I want to compile is placed.

It means compile sass from `src` folder and send compiled files to `src` folder.

In this case css file will be placed on same place where sass file already is.

Answer (score 0):

With node-sass for me is working to set Arguments to
`$FileName$ -o . $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`

and unchecked "Create output file from stdout".