# Correct PhpStorm node-sass syntax in "File Watchers" "Arguments" field

Tags: css, node.js, phpstorm, node-sass

**node-sass** syntax described at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass and https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass#command-line-interface does not work for PhpStorm ***File Watchers***.

Following the instructions in those links, I have tried different combinations and positions in the "Arguments" field with no success. I also checked all similar questions on this subject but none answers my question:

Can anybody help me with the correct syntax to compile a minified file with a filename ending with **.min.css**, in a directory different from the source directory?

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is perfectly valid and it has an answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57102994/file-watcher-an-output-directory-must-be-specified-when-compiling-a-directory/59114570).

Answer (score 0):

`node-sass` cli syntax does definitely work in file watchers, just in the same way as in command line. Suggested syntax to save the compressed `.css` file in `<project root dir>/css` folder is

```
$FileName$ --output-style=compressed --source-map=true -o $ProjectFileDir$/css
```

there doesn't seem to be a way to pass the target file name when using `-o` option. If you are aware of any, modify the arguments accordingly

[image]

Comment: This answer DOES NOT answer my question. Found the correct answer. and there is indeed a way to do exactly what I want. Check @Felipe Alameda A answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57102994/file-watcher-an-output-directory-must-be-specified-when-compiling-a-directory/59114570).